# How to add an error handling to read an XML file in php?

Tags: php, xml

I am developing a PHP script that allows me to modify tags in an XML file and move them once done.

My script works correctly but I would like to add error handling: So that if the result of my SQL query does not return anything display an error message or better, send a mail, and not move the file with the error and move to the next.

I did some tests but the code never displays the error and it moves the file anyway.

Can someone help me to understand why? Thanks

```
<?php


            

            }
         
        }

        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->save($source_file);
        rename($source_file,$destination_file);
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($barcode)` gives what? `$result[GEAN]` should be `$result['GEAN']`. You also are open to SQL injections

Comment: If I put a var_dump in my if (is_null($barcode)) loop it doesn't display anything. Yes I know but this is a test version for errors, I will do the prepared query part after

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try

```php
$result = odbc_fetch_array($exec);

if ($result === false || $result['GEAN'] === null) {
    echo "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE";
    // continue;
}

$barcode = (string) $result['GEAN'];
echo $barcode; echo "<br>"; //9353970875729   
            
$node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->nodeValue = "";
$node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($result[GEAN]));
```

Comment: Great! I do get the error message. However I would like that if in an XML file the GEAN is not found to continue the script but at the end not to move this file and pass to the others. What do I have to change?